# A question on primitive roots

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. How can Ihow that $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ iff $a^{(p-1)/q}\ncong 1 \pmod{p}$ for all prime divisors $q$ of $p-1$. Thanks

Comment: $\LaTeX$ tip: to get the `(mod p)`, use `\pmod{p}`. It will supply the spacing, the parentheses, and the roman typeface `mod`.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thanks for the latex tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you can see one direction: if $a^{(p-1)/q}\equiv1\pmod p$ then $a$ is not a primitive root.

Now suppose $a$ is not a primitive root. Then $a^d\equiv1\pmod p$ for some proper divisor $d$ of $p-1$. So all you have to show is that every proper divisor of $p-1$ is a divisor of $(p-1)/q$ for some prime divisor $q$ of $p-1$.

Comment: ah, yes, thank you for that.